# Where can I get people to test my game?

Tags: html5, browser-based-games, testing, playtesting

I've just finished making the core aspects of my HTML5 game. I have a server and all that, but is there a site where I can find people that would test my game? I figured that getting my friends to do it wouldn't be a good option because they are probably biased, so I need people that I never met before, complete strangers. Also, would the people at gamedev forums be willing to do that? Would it be considered as advertising?

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development :D

Comment: I'd go with what @N0xus said. You just want to get it out everywhere you can. And if you just so happened to drop a link in the comments or something then I'm sure I'd check it out :D

Comment: And at least put a link on your profile page ;)

Comment: When I said that I have a server, I only meant that. No domain name, the server isn't really mine (a friend lets me use it for stuff), and I shut the process down after some testing that I do. As soon as I register a domain name and rent my own dedicated server, then I'll start advertising. I was just getting the info up front. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Best advice I could give is to put what you have up, making it clear that it is still a beta and that you want people to play test it and link to it everywhere. This includes every game site you can think of include gamedev.net, moddb, here, facebook, twitter.

There is nothing wrong with advertising mate. How else are you going to get people to play your game? Just be clear and concise, and you'd be shocked at how friendly the game community is.